# Ansible: error while evaluating conditional

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

What am I doing wrong with this playbook?

```
$ cat check_only_centos7_tmp.yml
- hosts: myhosts
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
        - name: Check Uptime
          command: uptime
          when: ansible_distribution == "CentOS"
```

Error:

```
fatal: [server.myhost.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_distribution == \"CentOS\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_distribution == \"CentOS\"): 'ansible_distribution' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/ansible_playbooks/check_only_centos7_tmp.yml': line 11, column 11, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n        - name: Check Uptime\n          ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't have `gather_facts: true` ansible doesn't know what is `ansible_distribution` value. It's discovered from managed hosts.

Comment: My bad, I totally missed that :) Thanks a lot.